# Split residence

Tags: united-states, tax-residency

My question is related to split residency.  I am moving to Florida from Hawaii.  My wife refuses to leave Hawaii and is going to stay in her house.  She is retired and has a pension and social security for income.  I will be getting a new job in Florida and want to establish residence and homestead. My primary resident will be in Florida and hers will be in Hawaii.  We will be effectively separated but not officially.  Do we have to get formally separated or divorce for tax purposes?

Comment: Are you asking if you *have* to be separated or divorced? Clearly the answer is no. Many married couples live apart. Or are you asking if it would be to your benefit tax-wise?

Answer (score 2):

Given the situation you can file “married filing separately.” But the details, especially my knowing Fla has no state tax, points to filing single as being a better option. And you need a divorce for that.